# Search words in range on Sheet1 in list of words on Sheet2 and if match then clear word on Sheet1

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of names on one sheet (InputSheet) in the range c6:H200.  The names in this range change twice a month.  The group of names in the InputSheet are compared to a list of names on another sheet (NameList) in the range e2:e50.  For each name that is found on the NameList, I want to remove the name on the InputSheet.  I'm new to vba but have written this code and it is not working (getting run time error).  Thanks for any help!

```
 Sub RemoveNonWords()

Dim datasheet As Worksheet
Dim cl As Range

Set wordrange = InputSheet.Range("C6:h200")
Set datasheet = NameList.Range("E1:E50").Value   

  For Each cl In wordrange
    If cl = datasheet Then
       cl.Selection.ClearContents
    End If
  Next

Range("A6").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong with your posted code.  I think in the end, this is what you're looking for, code commented for clarity:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet
    Dim wsNames As Worksheet
    Dim rInputData As Range
    Dim rNameList As Range
    Dim DataCell As Range
    Dim rClear As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsInput = wb.Sheets("InputSheet")   'Change to the actual sheet name of your input sheet
    Set wsNames = wb.Sheets("NameList")     'Change to the actual sheet name of your name list sheet

    'Get last used row of the C:H columns in wsInput
    With wsInput.Range("C:H")
        lRow = .Find("*", .Cells(1), , , , xlPrevious).Row
        If lRow < 6 Then Exit Sub   'No data
    End With

    'Use the last used row to define your inputdata range, this was hardcoded to C6:H200 in your question
    Set rInputData = wsInput.Range("C6:H" & lRow)

    'Define the namelist range using all populated cells in column E of wsNames, this was hardcoded to E2:E50 in your question
    Set rNameList = wsNames.Range("E2", wsNames.Cells(wsNames.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
    If rNameList.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub  'No data

    'Data has been found and ranges assigned
    'Now loop through every cell in rInputData
    For Each DataCell In rInputData.Cells
        'Check if the cell being looked at exists in the NameList range
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rNameList, DataCell.Value) > 0 Then
            'Found to exist, add the cell to the Clear Range
            If rClear Is Nothing Then
                Set rClear = DataCell   'First matching cell added
            Else
                Set rClear = Union(rClear, DataCell)    'All subsequent matching cells added
            End If
        End If
    Next DataCell

    'Test if there were any matches and if so clear their contents
    If Not rClear Is Nothing Then rClear.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome!  This works perfectly!  Thank you for the quick response.